# Why two actions for a form?

Tags: forms, symfony

I've seen on the Symfony documentation and in the code generate automatically for CRUD of doctrine entities that two actions are created for the processing a form. One action "shows" the form for the first time (with one path) and then another one (with a different path) validates and process the form. In the case of an error this action shows the form again. I can't see why two actions with different paths ? I could just use one action with one path...

For instance

```
 /**
 * @Route("registrar")
 * @Template
 */
public function registerAction() {
    $usuario = new \Caja\LiquidacionesBundle\Entity\Usuario();

    $form = $this->createForm( new \Caja\LiquidacionesBundle\Form\UsuarioType(),
            $usuario,
            array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('usuario_crear')
            ));

    return array( 'form' => $form->createView() );        
}

/**
 * @Route("crear", name="usuario_crear" )
 * 
 */
public function createAction() {


    $usuario = new \Caja\LiquidacionesBundle\Entity\Usuario();
    $form = $this->createForm(new \Caja\LiquidacionesBundle\Form\UsuarioType, $usuario );


    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if( $form->isValid() )  {


        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');            

        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($usuario);
        $usuario->setPassword( $encoder->encodePassword( $usuario->getPassword(), $usuario->getSalt() ) );            

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist( $usuario );
        $em->flush();

        //TODO: Change this shit
        return new Response( "Usuario creado con exito." );            
    }

    return $this->render( 'CajaLiquidacionesBundle:Usuario:registrarUsuario.html.twig',
                array( 'form' => $form->createView() )
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could of course use one action and then decide if the request method is `POST` process the form or when it's `GET` just deliver the form. The argument against that is that your controller action becomes bigger and contains more logic. If that's okay for you feel free to use one action.

Comment: If you configure the form to be POST the isValid() method will return false and the form will be rendered anyway...
I could just use the path of the second action to do all the process (i.e. http://domain.com/crear). I wouldn't need to add anything to the action.

Comment: Don't get it. You asked if you could do this in one action. Now you tell me that you can simply use the second action? :D

Comment: Haha, I know i could do it just with the second action... It will show the form and processes it ... 
But because I see on the Symfony documentation that they use two actions (and two paths) I wanted to know what was the advantage of doing that.
Here's what i'm talking about: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html#handling-the-form-submission . Why not just one action that shows and process the form ? isValid() will return false in the processing action and the form will be rendered anyway...
I thought there might be a reason ...

Comment: First of all you can use one action to validate and save objects of create and edit actions. Further more you can create routes only to POST request leading to "saveObjectAction"